# AWS Lex Whatsapp Bot wont move on to the next utterance/intent it keeps repeating the greeting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, whatsapi

I created a custom Bot on AWS lex and Integrated it to WhatsApp using Lambda, the problem arises when im testing on WhatsApp ... It doesnt follow the conversation flow from the lex Bot instead it just repeats the intro message no matter what utterance/intent I use.

Also it doesnt allow me to use lex Fulfillment when i want add my Lambda function, Any help will be much appreciated guys, Documentation or anything !

Ive tried adding extra slots and SlotTypes in my intents, Ive Also set all my intents to $Latest.